# Tire Replacement

Tags: toyota, tires

In October, I bought new tires for my 2012 Toyota All-Wheel Drive Highlander.  I have only put 4000 miles on them as I have not been able to drive since March due to surgery. Tonight, a family member driving the car ran over a curb and burst the left-front tire.

Since the tires are only a few months old and I have only a few thousand miles on them, is it safe to only replace one tire?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is safe to replace only the single tire. I would bet you have less than 5% wear on your tires, which means not a whole bunch. You shouldn't cause any issues with anti-lock brakes or anything. Personally, I would only change the one and not worry about it.

Comment: Agreed providing you are using an identical tire (brand, size, style) as the original.

Comment: @mikes - Very good and valid point. I was taking it for granted that is what the OP was suggesting. Very worth noting.